# Auto-filling empty cells with Google Sheets' query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a table with data that I want to run a `QUERY` from.

In the output tab I need just one column from the data tab, but also I have 3 empty columns in the output tab, ***that are not in the data tab***, that I need to be filled automatically, based on conditions, preferably with the `QUERY`.

I am using a simple `QUERY` formula to load the data that I have in the source tab to the output tab.

`=QUERY('Source'!$A$1:$X, "SELECT A WHERE F IS NOT NULL", 1)`

The issue is that I can not have any other formulas in the output sheet, rather than the `QUERY` itself, as some issues arise when exporting Google Sheet that contains formulas to .CSV.

Regardless if the above is true or not, these are the rules...

This is the output that I need to have:

```
+---------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Country | Researched | Status            | Reason          |
+---------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| UK      | TRUE       | In Progress       |                 |
+---------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| US      | TRUE       | Unable to Proceed | Not a UK member |
+---------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Column 1 is what the `QUERY` extracts from the source.

Columns 2 to 4 are the ones that I need to create with the `QUERY`.

The value of each cell in those columns depends on column 1, except for column 2 that needs to have the value "TRUE" for each record.

Is it possible to implement multiple conditions in the `QUERY` itself, that will fill the empty columns in the output tab, based on conditions?

Comment: A little hint on the downvote?

Comment: Question edited to be more specific.

Comment: @player0, Thank you for the pointers and edit of the question. Will be providing more the requested in a moment.

Comment: @player0, apologies for the delay.

I hope the edit sheds some more light on the problem that I am having.

Comment: Apologies, @player0. I am afraid I can not share the sheet itself or a copy... However, the fields   `Status` and  `Reason` are generated, based on the criteria, wether or not the `Country` is "UK" or not.

Comment: so only UK is `In Progress` and anything else is `Unable to Proceed | Not a UK member` ? if not pls list me all countries that are UK members

Comment: What I need is the logic of how to implement the approach of creating new columns and filling them with static values (column 2) and conditional values (columns 3 and 4), preferably with the `QUERY`, without the use of `IF`, as I have read that it is bad practice.

Comment: You are exact @player0. This is exactly the condition

Comment: @player0, If it is the only way to do it. Apart from that what other hints can you give me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188527/discussion-between-i--newb-and-player0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY({QUERY(Source!$A$1:$X, 
        "select A, 'TRUE' 
         where F is not null
         label 'TRUE' 'Researched'", 1),
        QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
        QUERY(Source!$A$2:$X, 
        "select A 
         where F is not null", 0), 
        {"UK", "In Progress", ""}, {2, 3}, 0), 
        {"Unable to Proceed", "Not a UK member"})), 
        "select * 
         label Col1 'Status', Col2 'Reason'", 0)}, , 0)
```

[image]

Comment: the solution that you have provided works perfectly. Thank you very much. I have some questions that I'd like to ask you in the chat, if it is convenient for you?

Comment: sure, ask anytime